# Add single GLCanvas to multiple JFrames

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I'm a newbie to JOGL, so please forgive my ignorance if this is a silly question.

I have a java app where I have a GLCanvas rendering properly to a JFrame. My problem is that I want to place this GLCanvas in a different dialog/frame within the same EDT.

Let me give some context to this problem.

- The mainframe has the GLCanvas and renders properly
- Within another modal frame, there are images of the gl scene created using `Screenshot.readToBufferedImage(width, height)` routine;
- I have a button for the users to change the orientation of these images
- This button pops up another dialog/frame in which I want to display the current gl scene and allow the users to rotate the scene.
- Currently this dialog implements Runnable and is invoked via `EventQueue.invokeLater()` routine.
- On accepting the scene, I then take the updated gl camera orientation and use it to created the new image of the scene.

This does what I want on the first iteration. However if I try to change the orientation again or I exit and return to the mainframe and try to either rotate or zoom the scene, I get the following crash:

```
Process:         java [21036]
Path:            /usr/bin/java
Identifier:      com.apple.javajdk16.cmd
Version:         1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  java [20310]

PlugIn Path:       /Users/matthewalderson/.netbeans/7.1.2/jogl-runtime/jogl.jar-natives-macosx-universal/libjogl.jnilib
PlugIn Identifier: libjogl.jnilib
PlugIn Version:    ??? (???)

Date/Time:       2015-10-03 15:27:27.061 -0300
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000008
Crashed Thread:  17  Java: AWT-EventQueue-0

Application Specific Information:

Java information:
 Exception type: Bus Error (0xa) at pc=129df776d

 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.65-b04-462 mixed mode macosx-amd64)

Current thread (1040ac800):  JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native, id=691781632, stack(1292bc000,1293bc000)]
Stack: [1292bc000,1293bc000]
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.sun.opengl.impl.GLImpl.glDrawArrays(III)V+0
j  com.protocase.space.gl.VBOList.render(Ljavax/media/opengl/GL;)V+140
j  com.protocase.viewer.rendering.RenderVBOsVisitor.renderTopVBO(Lcom/protocase/things/solids/Solid;)V+96
j  com.protocase.viewer.rendering.RenderVBOsVisitor.renderSolidVBOs(Lcom/protocase/things/solids/Solid;)V+2
j  com.protocase.viewer.rendering.RenderVBOsVisitor.visitOneThing3D(Lcom/protocase/things/Thing3D;)V+128
j  com.protocase.viewer.rendering.RenderVBOsVisitor.visitThing3Ds(Lcom/protocase/things/Thing3D;)V+108
j  com.protocase.viewer.rendering.RenderVBOsVisitor.visitChildren(Lcom/protocase/things/Thing3D;)V+43
j  com.protocase.viewer.rendering.RenderVBOsVisitor.visitThing3Ds(Lcom/protocase/things/Thing3D;)V+113
j  com.protocase.viewer.rendering.RenderVBOsVisitor.visitChildren(Lcom/protocase/things/Thing3D;)V+43
j  com.protocase.viewer.rendering.RenderVBOsVisitor.visitThing3Ds(Lcom/protocase/things/Thing3D;)V+113
j  com.protocase.viewer.rendering.RenderVBOsVisitor.performOn(Lcom/protocase/things/Assembly;Ljavax/media/opengl/GL;Lcom/protocase/space/gl/GLPropertyModel;Lcom/protocase/space/gl/GLGraphicsManager;)V+58
j  com.protocase.space.gl.GLRenderVBOsState.renderGL(Ljavax/media/opengl/GL;Lcom/protocase/space/gl/GLGraphicsManager;)V+23
j  com.protocase.space.gl.GLRenderState.renderVisibleLines(Ljavax/media/opengl/GL;ZLcom/protocase/space/gl/GLGraphicsManager;)V+60
j  com.protocase.space.gl.GLRenderState.renderGLFill(Ljavax/media/opengl/GL;Lcom/protocase/space/gl/GLGraphicsManager;)V+20
j  com.protocase.space.gl.GLRenderState.render(Ljavax/media/opengl/GL;Lcom/protocase/space/gl/GLGraphicsManager;)V+33
j  com.protocase.space.gl.GLRenderState.run(Ljavax/media/opengl/GL;)V+13
j  com.protocase.viewer.rendering.Renderer3D.display(Ljavax/media/opengl/GLAutoDrawable;)V+83
j  com.sun.opengl.impl.GLDrawableHelper.display(Ljavax/media/opengl/GLAutoDrawable;)V+29
J  javax.media.opengl.GLJPanel$Updater.display(Ljavax/media/opengl/GLAutoDrawable;)V
j  com.sun.opengl.impl.GLDrawableHelper.display(Ljavax/media/opengl/GLAutoDrawable;)V+29
j  com.sun.opengl.impl.GLPbufferImpl$DisplayAction.run()V+11
j  com.sun.opengl.impl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(Ljavax/media/opengl/GLDrawable;Ljavax/media/opengl/GLContext;Ljava/lang/Runnable;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+418
j  com.sun.opengl.impl.GLPbufferImpl.maybeDoSingleThreadedWorkaround(Ljava/lang/Runnable;Ljava/lang/Runnable;Z)V+36
j  com.sun.opengl.impl.GLPbufferImpl.display()V+10
j  javax.media.opengl.GLJPanel.paintComponent(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V+237
j  javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V+290
j  javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V+512
j  javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V+322
j  javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V+512
j  javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V+322
j  javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V+73
j  javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V+512
j  javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V+322
j  java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Ljava/awt/Component;Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V+27
j  sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Ljava/awt/Component;Ljava/awt/Rectangle;Ljava/awt/Graphics;Ljava/awt/Shape;I)V+155
j  sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents([Ljava/awt/Component;Ljava/awt/Graphics;I)V+104
j  java.awt.Container.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V+98
j  java.awt.Window.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V+72
j  sun.awt.RepaintArea.paintComponent(Ljava/awt/Component;Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V+6
j  sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(Ljava/lang/Object;Z)V+368
j  apple.awt.ComponentModel.handleEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+70
j  apple.awt.CWindow.handleEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+95
j  java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+861
j  java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+42
j  java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+65
j  java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+2
j  java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+41
j  java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Ljava/awt/EventQueue;Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+3
j  java.awt.EventQueue$2.run()Ljava/lang/Void;+12
j  java.awt.EventQueue$2.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+28
j  java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Void;+11
j  java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+28
j  java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+73
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(I)Z+204
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/EventFilter;)V+30
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/Component;)V+11
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(ILjava/awt/Conditional;)V+4
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Ljava/awt/Conditional;)V+3
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run()V+9
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

I'm not sure this is enough information to give a sensible answer, but any help would help.

Couple more notes:

- If I don't use `EventQueue.invokeLater`, the background of the scene renders, but not the actual geometric objects
- For dependency reasons, I'm using OpenGL 1.2.

Comment: Please use JOGL 2 instead of JOGL 1. The maintenance of JOGL 1 was stopped about 5 years ago. I remind you that JOGL 2 supports OpenGL from 1.1 to 4.x. You have absolutely no chance to make it work and we can't even build JOGL 1 now. I advise you to use the latest release candidate of JOGL 2.3.2. The public API has changed a lot but feel free to contact us on our official forum if you need some help: http://forum.jogamp.org

Comment: Moreover, the problem comes probably from your code, you seem to badly manage the position of a direct NIO buffer. It is the most obvious reason explaining a crash in glDrawArrays. Please provide a SSCCE: http://sscce.org

Comment: Thank you for your response. We are currently using JOGL 1.8 and are going to look into upgrading to JOGL 2.3.2 in the near future.

Comment: JOGL 1.8 doesn't exist. The last public version of JOGL released by Oracle was JOGL 1.1.